# How to Regex for static webpage on Google App Engine?

Tags: html, regex, google-app-engine, static

I have a Static site I wish to upload to Google Apps, I am having trouble with the Regex side and would like some help, either explaining what I've done wrong or pointing me to resource which may help.

Below is what I've done so far:

**Site structure**

- my-static-site (not my real app name)

  - dist

    - about
    - blog

      - post-1

        - index.html
    - images
    - project

      - project-1

        - index.html
    - scripts
    - styles
    - about.html
    - archives.html
    - index.html
    - project.html

**app.yaml code**

```
application: my-static-site
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: dist

# to load my-static-site.appspot.com/project/project-1
- url: /project/project-1/
  static_files: dist/project/project-1/index.html
  upload: dist/project/project-1/index.html

# to load my-static-site.appspot.com/blog/post-1
- url: /blog/post-1/
  static_files: dist/blog/post-1/index.html
  upload: dist/blog/post-1/index.html
```

**How this behaves**

Going to my-static-site.appspot.com shows the correct home page with styling, scripts etc.

Clicking on the served 'post 1' link in the blog section redirects to my-static-site.appspot.com/blog/post-1/ and presents a blank screen, so the index.html is not being shown here. This is the same for the 'project 1' link in the project section.

However, if i manually append index.html to either the project of blog url, the content is served. E.g. my-static-site.appspot.com/blog/post-1/index.html shows correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: which rule have you written that you expect to handle the url /blog/post1/ ? i don't see any.

Comment: Why are you bothering within individual regexes at all, given that your file structure matches your desired site structure?

Comment: @StuartLangley- Thanks for the feedback, i've edit the app.yaml to have a rule for the post and project but still have the same problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - What is the best way to serve the index.html file within the project folder when the URL is www.site.com/project/projectname/ ? serving /dist/project/projectname/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played around and found order matters in Regex, this is what works:

```
application: my-static-site
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /(.+)/(.+)/
  static_files: dist/\1/\2/index.html
  upload: dist/(.+)/(.+)/index.html

- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: dist
```

Locally the blog posts and project posts with url /blog/post-1 and /project/project-1 serve the index.html file in each dir.

If anyone has a more elegant solution feel free to chime in.

Comment: Although this works using GoogleAppEngineLauncher for localhost, I recieve and error: ERROR    2014-03-08 22:28:06,583 http_runtime.py:404] bad runtime process port [''] ... sre_constants.error: cannot refer to open group

Comment: this is to do with the \1 and \2, using double backslashes \\1 and \\2 fixes the error but the index.html for the blog and project posts do not get served

Comment: Changed upload to use (.+) rather than back references, error is gone but when deploying to app engine I receive a 404 not found for resources /blog/post-1/ and /project/project-1/. The local deployment shows the correct index.html content. Any help appreciated

Comment: Nevermind it works!, GAE was by default serving version 1 of my app, deleted it and set version 2 as default, all working now!!